# Angular2 select default value not working when ngModel and name attribute is used

Tags: javascript, angular2-forms

```
<select id="role" name="role" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.role" #role="ngModel" required>
    <option value="" >Select</option>
    <option value="leadAnalyst">Lead Analyst</option>
    <option value="analyst">Analyst</option>
    <option value="assistant">Assistant</option>
</select>
```

user-create.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.user.role = 'Select';
}
```

I have tried using above code but its not working.

Comment: did the answer help

Comment: @Sajeetharan your answer works without error in console if #role="ngModel" is removed. And I need #role="ngModel" for validation purpose

Comment: you can still validate using ngModel

Comment: yes , thank you @Sajeetharan )

Comment: `user: User;`

`defaultStr = string`

`ngOnInit(){
this.user.role = this.defaultStr
}`

SCREENSHOT
 
https://prnt.sc/h3rub4

doesnt appear on select , Html is same as you used on plunker

Comment: check any error on console. if its same it should work

Comment: I think you have error in console in plunker, if you fix that error , default value wont be selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157781/discussion-between-saroj-maharjan-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 1):

You need to define user as a object and then assign the value for the role,

```
export class AppComponent {
  defaultStr = 'Select';
  user = { role: this.defaultStr };

  constructor() { console.clear(); }
  getvalue(){
    console.log(this.user.role);
  }
}
```

**[`WORKING DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vy9DxisdF2G7MymKiaOV?p=preview)**

Comment: in my above select I have #role="ngModel" , its for validation purpose.
If I add that as you havent added in your working demo.
It doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to :

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.user.role = '';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting the default value you need to use selected property of angular

```
 <select id="role" name="role" class="form-control"  #role="ngModel" required>
    <option value="" >Select</option>
    <option value="leadAnalyst" [selected]="'leadAnalyst' == user.role">Lead Analyst</option>
    <option value="analyst" [selected]="'Analyst' == user.role">Analyst</option>
    <option value="assistant" [selected]="'assistant' == user.role">Assistant</option>
</select>
```

"User.role" should return the role of user in ngOnInit()